# Why doesn't this fork into the background?

Tags: python, background-process

I want to fork into the background to run a long-running function, with the parent exiting immediately. I can't use `os.fork()` because I need Windows support. This is what I came up with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import multiprocessing
import time

def long_running_function(timeout=30):
    time.sleep(timeout)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    multiprocessing.Process(target=long_running_function).start()
```

It *does* spawn a child process: `ps` shows two Python processes with the same command string. However, on both my Mac and the Windows machine I tried it on, it acts as if I'd called `join()` on the `Process`: both parent and child keep running, and if I do <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd>, both die. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just wonder, is this possible? So on linux if you ctrl+C the main python process the forked process continues to run, correct?

Comment: What are you using this for? Keeping a program running after `^C` is usually an anti-pattern.

Comment: @laike9m Yes. Programs that start daemons use this model (fork, exec, parent exits), including some (most?) init scripts.

Comment: @LambdaFairy I'm not trying to ignore `^C` specifically (besides, that's a different issue, involving [`signal`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html)); I'm trying to fork into the background.

Comment: @laike9m Actually, I shouldn't _have_ to signal the parent: it should exit immediately after starting the child, having nothing else to do. Just like an init script.

Answer (score -3):

To start multiprocessing Process can fork but it is not required. Process uses a similar API as Threading does which does not cause a call to the fork() API from the OS. In Python a simple fork example would be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""A basic fork in action"""

import os

def my_fork():
    child_pid = os.fork()
    if child_pid == 0:
        print "Child Process: PID# %s" % os.getpid()
    else:
        print "Parent Process: PID# %s" % os.getpid()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_fork()
```

Notice how we're importing the os library. In your example you aren't causing fork() to never be called.

Please note that on Windows, fork() does not exist so you cannot fork as you will be able to on *nix systems.

Please see [HERE](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-multiprocessing/) for a good article explaining forking in Python.

Comment: Asker specifically states he cannot use `os.fork()`.

Comment: Specifically because I need Windows compatability.

Comment: Did you read the article? I mean it does explain how to use multiprocessing/subprocess/Process properly in order to obtain what you are looking for. I know that os.fork() is not available everywhere, I mentioned that. Anyways, hopefully that article helps you.

Comment: Here's the full link to the article, just in case. https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-multiprocessing/